# Is there an equivalent to an ECDF with a "<" sign?

Tags: probability, distributions, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

The empirical cumulative distribution function is defined as

$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb I_{x_i \leq x}
$$

Is there an equivalent interpretation of this function as:
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb I_{x_i<x}
$$

The reason I ask is that I have a distribution of non-negative values, around 40% of which are zero. If I evaluate $F(0)$ using the standard ECDF formula I get $F(0)=0.4$. But, for my purposes, I would like to have $F(0)=0$ (i.e., there are no values *less than* zero).

Does such a function exist?

Comment: Under the usual definition $F(0 - \varepsilon)$ still gives the correct answer. So it is a question to you if you want a $F(x) = \Pr(x \le X)$ or something else.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion for $F(0-\epsilon)$ makes sense - and will be easy to integrate into my code in R.

Comment: *"But, for my purposes, I would like to have $F(0)=0$ (i.e., there are no values _less than_ zero). "* This makes me curious. Why would you like to have this?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I am creating an index that is a weighted average over multiple variables, and I don't want the importance of the zero values to be over-inflated. In my particular case the index represents the weight of evidence for alternative food networks in different administrative areas across Europe. If one of my variables (e.g., number of farmers' markets) is zero 40% of the time, I want these regions to receive a score of zero for that variable (i.e., $F(0)=0$), rather than $0.4$, as this would begin to counteract the effects of other variables. Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: If $F(0) = 0$ by definition, and data has no influence on it, then you can just as well leave it out of the computation of your index. Also for discrete variables, if we have $F(x) = P(X\leq x)$ and $F^\prime(x) = P(X < x)$ then we just have a shift $F(x) = F^\prime(x-1)$. This makes the underlying problem interesting. Why do you need to play tricks with definition like a CDF when you can also change a formula by using $x-1$ instead of $x$. It seems a bit devious and as if an underlying problem is 'solved' only in an indirect way by dodging the symptoms of the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remember how the CDF is a right-continuous function? That comes from using the $\le$.

If you use $<$, then you change the function to be left-continuous.

Regarding your exact question about if such a function exists, the answer is that it does, and you wrote out exactly what it is. That function isn’t the classical CDF, but if it has meaning for your application, use it!

[Apparently Kolmogorov used the $<$ convention and left-continuity in his first probability book](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1807136/672549), so you might consider yourself to be in good company by thinking this is reasonable!

Comment: [Some French courses](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~leroux/probabilitesbis/node6.html) keep Kolmorogov's convention alive